# Azure devops not able to connect to jfrog Artifactory

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, artifactory

We are using jfrog Artifactory cloud to store maven dependency. we are using these dependencies in pom file. We are able to build from local file as we have added jfrog credentials in .m2/settings.xml file.
When we try to run this same thing from azure devops yaml file we are getting authentication error (401 error code)and due to that libraries are not getting download and build is failed.
We have added the service connection in azure devops and it is able to connect to jfrog.
how to configure build pipeline to access jfrog Artifactory to access libraries?

```
trigger:
  - main

pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

steps:
  - checkout: self
    lfs: true
  - task: ArtifactoryToolsInstaller@1
    inputs:
      artifactoryService: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      cliInstallationRepo: 'jfrog-cli'
      installExtractors: true
      extractorsInstallationRepo: 'jcenter'
  - task: ArtifactoryGenericDownload@3
    inputs:
      specSource: 'taskConfiguration'
      fileSpec: |
        {
          "files": [
            {
              "pattern": "repo/*jar",
              "target": $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/lib
            }
          ]
        }
      failNoOp: true
  - task: Maven@3
    inputs:
      mavenPomFile: "pom.xml"
      mavenOptions: "-Xmx3072m"
      javaHomeOption: "JDKVersion"
      jdkVersionOption: "1.8"
      jdkArchitectureOption: "x64"
      publishJUnitResults: true
      testResultsFiles: "**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml"
      goals: "package"
  - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/target/test.jar
    artifact: artifact
```

Comment: How does your yaml look like? Are you using the official JFrog Artifactory Azure DevOps extension?

Comment: Updated yaml file. Yes we are using  JFrog Artifactory Azure DevOps extension. We are not able to configure it properly looks like. tried with multiple task which comes with extn,

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the Maven task, which is not supported by the Artifactory Azure DevOps extension. This task does not utilize the Artifactory service connection that was configured.

Instead, I'd recommend using the ArtifactoryMaven task. Using this task enforces resolution and deployment to Artifactory and therefore, the settings.xml file is not necessary. This task also publishes to the relevant target deploy repositories.

Basic usage example:

```
- task: ArtifactoryMaven@1
inputs:
  mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
  goals: 'install'
  artifactoryResolverService: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  targetResolveReleaseRepo: 'libs-release'
  targetResolveSnapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot'
  artifactoryDeployService: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  targetDeployReleaseRepo: 'libs-release-local'
  targetDeploySnapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot-local'
```

You can read more about the Artifactory Maven task [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension#ArtifactoryAzureDevOpsExtension-TriggeringMavenBuilds).

Comment: We tried with artifactory maven task. With this also we we were getting the error.  Downloading from central: https://XXX.jfrog.io/artifactory/xxxx/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom. It was trying to access  all the libs from our artifactory, but we dont have all public libs in it.

Comment: Then, you can set the targetResolveReleaseRepo to resolve from jcenter remote repository or a virtual repository that contains it. See https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-is-a-remote-repository-and-how-does-it-work/

Comment: still getting the same error. Added most of the public repos as remote.
https://jcenter.bintray.com
https://jfrog.bintray.com/jfrog-cli-go/ 
https://maven.xwiki.org/externals/